# Is it possible to check whether System.Threading.EventWaitHandle can be opened without throwing exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, ipc, event-wait-handle

I have

```
try
{
    using (var eventWaitHandle = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(name))
    {
        eventWaitHandle.Set();
    }

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
catch(WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
{
    // register new handle code goes here
}
```

Is there any way to do that without throwing/handling exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `.NET 4.5` you can eliminate `WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException` exception for case when named system event does not exist by using `TryOpenExisting()` method:

```
EventWaitHandle result = null;
if (!EventWaitHandle.TryOpenExisting("eventName", out result))
{
   if (result == null)
   {
      // event was not found
   }else
   {
      // result represent a cross process WaitEvent handle
   }
}
```

---

```
public static bool TryOpenExisting(
                      string name,
                      out EventWaitHandle result
)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139128%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you are uncertain whether a named synchronization event exists, use
>   this method overload instead of the OpenExisting method overload,
>   which throws an exception if the synchronization event does not exist